# Time limit exceeds

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

There are N drivers participating in the Championship. They are all assigned points after each race, including the final one. The winner of the race is awarded N points, the runner-up gets N - 1 points, and so on until the last driver, who gets 1 point. Two drivers cannot finish a race in the same spot.

Write a program to calculate, based on the total number of points that each driver has earned before the final race, how many drivers still have a chance to have the largest total after the final race and thus win the Championship. If more than one driver has the same maximum point total, they are all awarded the World Champion title.

I am getting time limit exceeded for all test cases and My code is failing for one test case for 100 participants. 
Test cases are:

test case-1:
3
10
9
8
output-3
test case-2:
5
15
14
12
14
15
output-4
Here is my code:

```
n=int(input())
b=[]
for i in range(n) :
    b.append(int(input()))
l=len(b)
c=l
sort(b)-->>> some sorting algo to sort in O(n*logn)
for i in range(len(b)) :
    x=b[i]
    x+=l
    for j in range(i+1,len(b)) :
        l-=1
        y=b[j]
        y+=l
        if y>x :
            c-=1
            break
print(c)``
```

Comment: What test cases? Show us! And formulate a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overcomplicate things, this can be easily solved in O(NlogN), assume `results` is the current results of the drivers and `N` is the number of the drivers. All you have to do is:

```
N = 5
results = [ 15, 14, 12, 14, 15 ]
# find who can achieve the highest result
max_points = max([a+b for a,b in enumerate(sorted(results, reverse=True))])
# now count how many drivers can get as much as "max_points"
has_potential = [ 1 for r in results if r+N-1 >= max_points ]
print len(has_potential)   # print the result
```

output:

```
4
```

Comment: for this input output is 4 not 5